# Take the derivative of this likelihood function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$\displaystyle L=-\frac {n}{2}\log(2\pi \sigma^2)-\frac {1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)^2$

Take the derivative with respect to $\sigma^2$ and $\mu_y$.

$\displaystyle \frac {\partial L}{\partial \mu_y}=\frac {1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)$

$\displaystyle \frac {\partial L}{\partial \sigma^2}=-\frac {n}{2\sigma^2}+\frac {1}{2\sigma^4}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)^2$

Can someone tell me if this is correct? The answer given in the problem set looks wrong, so help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct!

Note that:

$L=-\frac {n}{2}\log(2\pi \sigma^2)-\frac {1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)^2$

$=-n\log(2\pi)-\frac {n}{2}\log(\sigma^2)-\frac {1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(Y_i-\mu_y)^2$.